# Get JS varible to PHP variable with an onclick function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to have a button that run my js function onclick and take the variable data and send it to result.php file. How can i do that

My code simplified:

```js
function Run() {
  var Variable0 = document.getElementById("ElementX");
}
```

```html
<form action="result.php" method="GET">
  <button class="CLASSx" id="IDy" onclick="Run()">CLICK</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You can use a hidden input that will pass the information as a GET parameter to `result.php`. However, you are trying to pass an element... which doesn't make a lot of sense. Are you trying to pass the element's value? Inner text? Inner HTML?

Comment: You write your php script to accept data from post in json format.  Your javascript code sends data to the php script using ajax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a Javascript variable in to PHP using an onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46636281/how-to-pass-a-javascript-variable-in-to-php-using-an-onclick-event)

Answer (score -1):

You can write like this:

```
<form action="result.php" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="var_name" value="your value">
    <button class="CLASSx" id="IDy" onclick="Run()">CLICK</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Ajax like this:

```
function Run() {
  var Variable0 = document.getElementById("ElementX");

 var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            {
                alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.open("get", `result.php?data=${Variable0}`); 
        xmlHttp.send(); 
}
```

**result.php**

```
<?php
   $date= $_GET["data"];
   // do what do you want here...
    $result = "custom result"
  echo $result
?>
```

Comment: who say that ?? the XHR is w3c and whatwg standard also fetch have some problems with older browser. up vote it.